# SQL Server slow down after duplicating database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I recently moved a bunch of tables from an existing database into a new database due to the database getting rather large. After doing so I noticed a dramatic decrease in performance of my queries when running against the new database.

**The process I took to recreate the new database is this:**

1. Generate Table CREATE scripts using sql servers automatic script
   generator.
2. Run the create table scripts
3. Insert all data into new database
       using INSERT INTO with a select from
       the existing database.
4. Run all the alter scripts to create
       the foreign keys and any indexes

**Does anyone have any ideas of possible problems with my process, or some key step I'm missing that is causing this performance issue?**

Thanks.

Comment: you could also add filegroups to the database and move tables into those filegroups. This way you still have 1 DB but you can backup filegroups separately

Comment: Is the hardware for the other database similar? Is it on the same type of storage? Is it using the same version of SQL Server? These things could definitely impact speed.

Comment: Are the query plans identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you script the indexes from the tables in the original database?  Missing indexes could certainly account for poor performance.

Comment: There was some missing indexes that failed to get carried over. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

first I would an a mimimum make sure that **auto create statistics** is enabled you can also set **auto update statistics** to true

after that I would update the stats by running

```
sp_updatestats
```

or

```
UPDATE STATISTICS
```

Also realize that the first time you hit the queries it will be slower because nothing will be cached in RAM. On the second hit should be much faster

Comment: I ensured that auto create statistics was enabled, and also ran UPDATE STATISTICS. I didn't notice a major improvement. Thanks though

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the execution plans on each server when running these queries - that should allow you to easily see if they're doing something different e.g. table scanning due to a missing index, poor statistics etc.

Are both DBs sat on the same box with their data files on the same drive arrays?

Comment: Finally - a suggestion to actually gather and evaluate evidence, rather than guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell *what* about those queries got slower? New access plans? Same plans but they perform slower? Do they *execute* slower or are they *suspended* more? Did *all* queries got slower or just some? And last but not least, *how do you know*, ie. what exactly did you measure and how?

Some of the usual suspects could be:

- The new storage is much slower (.mdf on slow disk, or on a busy disk)
- You changed the data structure during move (ie. some indexes did not get ported)
- You changed the data size (ie. compression options) resulting on more pages for the same data
- Did anything else change at the same time, new app code or anything the like?
- By extending the data size (you do no mention *deleting* the old tables) you are now trashing the buffer pool (did the page lifetime expectancy decreased in performance counters?)

Comment: +1 Also check the fragmentation; if you grew out the database as the files copied and you weren't on clean disks you may have fragmentation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Look on how you set up the initial size and growth options. If you didn't give it enough space to begin with or if you are growing by 1MB at a time that could be a cause of performance issues.

Comment: would this also effect queries though, or just when creating, updating, and deleting data?

Comment: @leaf - if this is a readonly db or if you are doing mostly reads, then growth wouldn't be an issue, most likely you have missing indexes or stale statitics.